# Most general renormalizable Lagrangian with 2 Weyl spinors and a complex scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, dimensional-analysis

I am asked to write down the most general Lorentz-invariant Lagrangian in 4d-spacetime which contains a left-handed Weyl spinor $\psi_{L}$ and a right-handed Weyl-spinor $\psi_{R}$ as well as a complex scalar field $\phi$, which is renormalizable and invariant under $\psi_{L}\to e^{i\alpha}\psi_{L}$ and $\phi\to e^{i\alpha}\phi$

(1) kinetic terms: 
$$\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{kin}}=\partial_{\mu}\phi^{\dagger}\partial^{\mu}\phi + i\psi^{\dagger}_{L}\overline{\sigma}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi_{L}+i\psi^{\dagger}_{R}\sigma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi_{R}$$
where $\sigma^{\mu}=(1,\sigma^{i})$ and $\overline{\sigma}^{\mu}=(1,-\sigma^{i})$ with the Pauli matrices $\sigma^{i}$.

(2) mass terms: The Dirac mass term $m(\psi_{R}^{\dagger}\psi_{L}+\psi_{L}^{\dagger}\psi_{R})$ as well as the Majorana mass term for $\psi_{L}$ are not invariant under the required symmetries, therefore we only have the mass term for the complex scalar field and the Majorana mass term for $\psi_{R}$:

$$\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{mass}}=-m_{\phi}\phi^{\dagger}\phi-\frac{m_{R}}{2}(i\psi_{R}^{T}\sigma^{2}\psi_{R}-i\psi_{R}^{\dagger}\sigma^{2}\psi_{R}^{\ast})$$

(3) Interactions: The only interactions I have found which have a coupling constant with a positive mass dimension or are dimensionless and which are invariant under the required symmetries are:

$$\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{int}}=-\frac{\lambda}{4}(\phi^{\dagger}\phi)^{2}-\frac{g}{2}(i\phi\psi_{R}^{T}\sigma^{2}\psi_{R}-i\phi^{\dagger}\psi^{\dagger}_{R}\sigma^{2}\psi_{R}^{\ast})$$

Therefore my solution is $$\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{kin}}+\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{mass}}+\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{int}}$$

Does this looks right? Have I forgotten something?